# Do Maven Requires Definitely Java in our System?

Tags: java

I am very confused regarding the installation of Maven with Eclipse. To use Maven with Eclipse, is it necessary to set an environment variable for the path to java?

I am newly joined employee, and am not familiar with this tool.

Comment: I am not entirely sure as to what you are asking for. Firstly, yes, Maven clearly requires Java, because it is meant for Java. Maven is used for managing a Java project. Secondly, as you are a newly joined employee, I would recommend you ask your co-workers (or an assigned mentor) to help you out, because companies generally have their own customized setups and conventions.

Comment: Among others, Maven compile and execute java code, so yes, is required.

Comment: Normally, the m2 plugin is included in Eclipse. You can also (and often should) point to an external maven instance. Question is, what are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: Have you done any homework before asking this?

Answer (score 2):

In a Java environment like Eclipse, you don't need to set the Java path. It is already set to the Eclipse environment and Maven can simply use it if you use the Maven plugin.

If you use Maven outside of Eclipse, you have to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.